# how to write a LaTeX macro for conditional compiling?

Tags: macros, latex

I want to write some notes in the draft of a LaTeX document, and at a later point I want to compile the document without them. I saw someone doing something like the following (but I forgot what he did). Write notes as `{\scriptsize some_text}`, and in the end replace all `{\scriptsize ...}` with `{}` with a `\newcommand`. But I can't figure out how to write a `\newcommand` to replace all `{\scriptsize some_text}` occurrences by empty strings. I can then just comment or uncomment the `\newcommand` line.

Comment: Note that there is a stack exchange site dedicated to LaTex - [http://tex.stackexchange.com/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). I have voted to close this question and move it to tex.stackexchange.com. In future, that is probably the best place for these sorts of questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about the tex.se. In fact I found an answer there. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not migrating this to Tex SE because you indicated you found an answer there, which means this is likely a duplicate of something that has been asked there.

Comment: Could you please link the answer you found on tex.sx so that people easily can find it if they end up here?

Comment: I have now forgotten which post it was, but the suggestion was to use the package "comment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare in the beginning of your file

```
\somevariabletrue
%\somevariablefalse
```

so you can quickly uncomment one and comment second, and in the later part of your code:

```
\ifsomevariable
  ...
\else
  ...
\fi
```